# NEST JS - Failed to Fetch while using normal fetch API?

Tags: fetch-api, nest

I am running a web application instance and recently have been getting a failed to fetch error:

```
at /Users/2023/pp_project/gzb-services/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17 {
  response: 'TypeError: fetch failed',
  status: 500,
  options: undefined
```

I checked for http endpoint and network connection (if there's a VPN or something) and those two look good to me. Can someone tell me what possibly could go wrong here?

Comment: From the status code it seems that the fault is on the server side.  
<https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500>  

If the server is running fine you might want to examine your fetch request.  You can try to create and verify that the request is working fine before writing the code to perform the same request. For that you can use for instance Postman - <https://www.postman.com/>